# R large dataframe conversions in parallel

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, bigdata, snow

Essentially I've got a large dataframe: 10,000,000x900 (rows,columns) and I'm trying to convert the class of each column in parallel. The end result needs to be a data.frame

Here's what I've got so far:

Pretend `df` is the dataframe already defined, all columns are a mixture of numeric and character classes

```
library(snow) 
cl=makeCluster(50,type="SOCK")
cl.out=clusterApplyLB(cl,df,function(x)factor(x,exclude=NULL))
```

`cl.out` is a list of what I want, except what I need is for this to be as a data.frame class

So this is where I get stuck... do I try and combine all of the elements of cl.out into a data.frame which isn't going to be in parallel? (SLOW, time is an issue)

Can I implement something else with a different package? (foreach?)

Do I have to hard-code some c to get this done efficiently?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

One useful paradigm is to subset and replace all columns, treating `df` as list-like

```
df[] <- lapply(df, factor, exclude=NULL)
```

Do you really have 50 cores on a single machine, as implied by your call to `makeCluster`? If you're not on a Windows machine, use the `parallel` package and `mclapply` instead

```
library(parallel)
options(mc.cores=50)
df[] <- mclapply(df, factor, exclude=NULL)
```

Is this really going to help you in your overall evaluation? It seems to cost as much to distribute and retrieve the data as to do the calculation.

```
> f = factor(rep("M", 10000000), levels=LETTERS)
> df = data.frame(f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f)
> system.time(lapply(df, factor, exclude=NULL))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.676   0.564   3.250 
> system.time(clusterApply(cl, df, factor, exclude=NULL))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.488   0.752   2.476 
> system.time(mclapply(df, factor, exclude=NULL))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.876   1.832   1.814
```

(the multi-core and multi-process timings are probably highly variable).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a data.frame of that size, I think you will be running into memory issues *very* quickly.

I think it will be much faster, and more efficient.

You could use `set`

```
library(data.table)

# to set as a data.table without having to copy 
setattr(df, 'class', c('data.table','data.frame')
alloc.col(df)

for(nn in names(df)){
   set(df, j = nn, value = factor(df[[nn]])
 }
```

It is worth reading [data.table and parallel computing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759905/data-table-and-parallel-computing)

Answer (score 0):

Since a data.frame is a list, with a `class` attribute,
you can just convert the list into a data.frame,
with `as.data.frame`.

```
cl.out <- as.data.frame(cl.out)
```

I notice that the column names are lost: if you are sure that they are
in the same order, you can set them back with:

```
names(cl.out) <- names(df)
```

Comment: The conversion is quite slow using that process. I believe there is more going on under the hood than simply appending a class attribute onto the blob of data.

Comment: It is not very clean, but you can try to change the attribute directly:
`class(cl.out) <- "data.frame"`.