# Parallel version of sapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Do we have parallel version of sapply, as we have mclapply in parallel package which is a version of lapply.

Comment: lapply and sapply is pretty much the same function except that sapply simplifies the results, so what sapply can do lapply can do as well, you just will need to do some postprocessing, ie `do.call("cbind", df)` or `do.call("c", df)`

Comment: You're looking like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759905/data-table-and-parallel-computing (at least insomuch as you've tagged data.table; there's surely a general R parallelization question, too)

Comment: @grrgrrbla Thanks, I think then I can use mclapply.

Answer (score 9):

As @RHertel points out, the `snow` package has apply family options, but it does not count with an `mcsapply` function as it is asked. If you take a look a the implementation of `sapply`, it is simply a call to `lapply` with some more post processing:

```r
sapply
#> function (X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE) 
#> {
#>     FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
#>     answer <- lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
#>     if (USE.NAMES && is.character(X) && is.null(names(answer))) 
#>         names(answer) <- X
#>     if (!isFALSE(simplify) && length(answer)) 
#>         simplify2array(answer, higher = (simplify == "array"))
#>     else answer
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x559a53feef18>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Since the `mclapply` function is equivalent to `lapply`, you could actually write your own replacing some parts of `sapply`, here is an example:

```r
# An mc-version of the sapply function.
mcsapply <- function (X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE) {
  FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
  answer <- parallel::mclapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
  if (USE.NAMES && is.character(X) && is.null(names(answer))) 
    names(answer) <- X
  if (!isFALSE(simplify) && length(answer)) 
    simplify2array(answer, higher = (simplify == "array"))
  else answer
}

# Testing it out
library(parallel)

ans0 <- mcsapply(1:20, function(i) rnorm(1e4), mc.cores = 4)
ans1 <- sapply(1:20, function(i) rnorm(1e4))

# Same structure
str(ans0)
#>  num [1:10000, 1:20] 0.1792 0.1581 -0.1293 -0.0324 0.1836 ...
str(ans1)
#>  num [1:10000, 1:20] 1.304 1.355 -1.387 1.07 0.582 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Finally, you can always create a Fork cluster and use `parSapply` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `snow` [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/) provides parallel versions of `apply()` and related functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mcmapply`, also from the parallel package (the default setting is `SIMPLIFY = TRUE`). https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/parallel/versions/3.4.1/topics/mclapply 
`mcmapply` is a parallelized and multivariate version of `sapply`, so it works if you input multiple lists. If you input just one list it is the same as `sapply`.

Answer (score -1):

In the event that your output could be coerced into an atomic vector, you can use `unlist(mclapply(....))`.

Comment: This is not necessarily true since you are assuming that the output of `mclapply` can be coerced to an atomic vector, which is not always the case.