# Split data.table in roughly equal parts alphabetically

Tags: r, csv, data.table, plyr

I am trying to split a relatively large data.table into roughly equal parts to output the names into csv files.
I've already implemented a solution based on [Split data.table into roughly equal parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125795/split-data-table-into-roughly-equal-parts)

```
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
dt <- data.table(Name =  letters)
bins <- 5
dt[order(-rank(Name)), Split.ID := as.integer(runif(.N,0,bins))]

d_ply(dt[order(-rank(Name))], .(Split.ID),
      function(sdf) write.csv(x = sdf[,1] , file = paste0("Output/test.",sdf$Split.ID[[1]],".csv"), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, eol = ", "))
```

The problem with this solution is that the ordering of the names in the csv files is alphabetical, but because of the randomness of the Split.ID it is not preserved for all csv files.

Comment: `dt[, g := .I %% 5]; split(dt, by="g")` seems to work. To confirm, check `dt[, .N, by=g]` for the counts. This doesn't split contiguous chunks of `dt`, but you could fix that fairly easily I guess. Also, per the answer in the link, you can do `dt[, write.csv(.SD, ...), by=g]` instead of `split`. Also, fyi, data.table's `fwrite` command can write csvs very efficiently if that's a concern.

Comment: Thanks for that, seems to be a lot easier, but it's not yet completely the desired result. I would like to have five consecutive letters in one csv file. So that inside one csv file everything is in the desired order.

Comment: That's just a matter of math... this seems to work: `dt[, g := cut(.I, breaks=5, labels=1:5)]`. By the way, looks like you don't need to load plyr here...?

Comment: Ah alright, thanks. I thought plyr is necessary for `d_ply` in my preliminiary code.

Comment: Oh, nope, my mistake. I didn't notice the `d_ply`; hadn't run your code that far.