# Control number of rows when binding dataframes with different number of rows?

Tags: r, functional-programming, dplyr, purrr

I have a dataframe generated by a function:
Each time it's of different number of rows:

```
structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c("er", "gd", "ku"), c = c(43, 
453, 12)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

structure(list(a = c(1, 2), b = c("er", "gd"), c = c(43, 453)), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want to be able like in a `while` loop to control the number of rows to be less then `n` (`n = 4, 100, 4242...`) when I bind rows.

Please advise how to do this using functional programming without a `while` loop?
I mean sometimes you will get `n = 10` and the df before bind_rows is 7 and after binding the last one it will be 20. It's ok, I want the number of rows to be `min_k (k >= n)`

Here is my while loop doing this:

```
b <- list()

total_rows <- 0

while(total_rows < 1000) {

  df <- f_produce_rand_df()

  b[[length(b) + 1]] <- df

  total_rows <- total_rows + nrow(df)

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the goal of this? Do you need the length of the resulting data.frame or do you want do combine them conditionally?

Comment: @hannes101 please look on my edited answer.

Comment: Still, I can't really see what you are trying to achieve and to be fair I can't really see what this code achieves.

Comment: @hannes101 what exactly you don't understand? I have explained, I am getting tons of dataframes, all of them with same columns. Is it ok until now?

Now I want to BIND them by rows, ok?

I want to control the bind operation, if the number of rows of the binded dataframe so far is more then specified n, stop binding and return df.

Is it clear?

Comment: sorry meant to be df.

Comment: @AndreElrico I have fixed it please advise.

Comment: why do you count the "number of dfs" if you are interessted in the number of rows?

Comment: Again, each df has it's own number of rows, it's different. @AndreElrico

Comment: I want to apply bind_rows for the df's up until the stop condition - the total number of rows is n or greater but if it's more then n, it should be the last df that contributes. @AndreElrico

Comment: well I can't help you with that. The while loop seems to be an appropriate function for your task.

Comment: Understood! Thanks guys!

Comment: Check out `rbindlist` from the `data.table` package or the `bind_rows()` function from the `dplyr` package. They most probably would speed this up. Perhaps with data.table and its speed you perhaps don't need to split it up anyways.

Comment: In general all looping constructs can be substituted by recursion. I am not entirely sure on the specifics of what you are trying to achieve but it's 100% doable with recursion.

Comment: Additionally to my comment on using `data.table` you can do just that and then afterwards split it for example like in this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125795/split-data-table-into-roughly-equal-parts